# React Material UI Slider

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, slider

I am using the react material UI slider and want to customize the color of the pointer from default value blue to pink? I have tried modifying the thumb and finger in withStyles object.But it doesn't work.

https://material-ui.com/components/slider/

[image: Slider Input Ponter]

I want to customize the color of the slider pointer.

Comment: Can you provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you're tried that isn't working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327393/how-to-change-material-ui-slider-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is makeStyles component that material UI library offers that helps overriding custom styles to styled components of material UI. Here is a little snapshot that might help you:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Slider from '@material-ui/core/Slider';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: 250,
  },
  sliderColor: {
    color: 'red'
  }
});

export default function InputSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center"
        <Grid item xs>
          <Slider
            value={typeof value === 'number' ? value : 0}
            onChange={handleSliderChange}
            aria-labelledby="input-slider"
            className={classes.sliderColor}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create a custom component like this:

```
const PrettoSlider = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: '#52af77',
    height: 8,
  },
  thumb: {
    height: 24,
    width: 24,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    border: '2px solid currentColor',
    marginTop: -8,
    marginLeft: -12,
    '&:focus, &:hover, &$active': {
      boxShadow: 'inherit',
    },
  },
  active: {},
  valueLabel: {
    left: 'calc(-50% + 4px)',
  },
  track: {
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
  rail: {
    height: 8,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
})(Slider);
```

2. and call this in your render like:

```
return {
...
 <PrettoSlider valueLabelDisplay="auto" aria-label="pretto slider" defaultValue={20} />
...
}
```

by https://material-ui.com/components/slider/ **Customed sliders**